# python lists in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple question. I know how to bring out(I don't know how to say besides 'bring out') from a list. for example,

```
Alist = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Then,

```
Alist[0] = 1
Alist[1] = 2
```

But, what if

```
Blist = [[1, 2, 3 ,4], [5, 6, 7]]
Blist[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Blist[1] = [5, 6, 7]
```

I can 'bring out' the whole [5,6,7] as calling Blists[1]

My question is, how to bring out specific number in the list, lets say number 5. Hope this makes sense

Comment: You mean `Blists[1][0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that `B[1]` gets you a reference to the second list in `B`.

```
lst = B[1]
```

You can index that result again to get another element

```
lst[0]
```

However you can of course do this more easily in one line

```
B[1][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Blist[1]** is a list itself.  To get the head element, use an index on **Blist[1]**

```
Blist[1][0]
```

Comment: Thank you ! I knew it's going to be simple, but I couldn't find the answer